# Problem with mocking pathlib.Path.is_dir()

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have code that checks if specified file is a dir:

```
from pathlib import Path

def simple_method():
    to_check = ['/tmp', '/tmp/test']
    print("")

    for element in to_check:
        path = Path(element)
        print(path)
        result = path.is_dir()
        print(f"#MBB SC: {dir} -> {result}")
        if result:
            print(f"{element} is a dir")
        else:
            print(f"{element} is not a dir")
```

I want to write test for it. In test scenario I want to mock pathlib.Path.is_dir() and set first call of is_dir (for /tmp) to True and second one (for /tmp/test) to False. This is how I wanted to solve it:

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import call, patch, MagicMock

import source_code

class TestSourceCode():
    def test(self):
        source_code.Path = MagicMock()
        source_code.Path.is_dir = MagicMock()

        source_code.Path.is_dir.side_effect = [True, False]

        source_code.simple_method()
        
        assert source_code.Path.call_args_list == [call('/tmp'), call('/tmp/test')]
        
        print(f"\n")
        print(f"source_code.Path")
        print(f"source_code.Path.call_count {source_code.Path.call_count}")
        print(f"source_code.Path.call_args {source_code.Path.call_args}")
        print(f"source_code.Path.method_calls {source_code.Path.method_calls}")
        print(f"source_code.Path.call_args_list {source_code.Path.call_args_list}")
        
        print(f"\n")
        print(f"source_code.Path.is_dir")
        print(f"source_code.Path.is_dir.call_count {source_code.Path.is_dir.call_count}")
        print(f"source_code.Path.is_dir.call_args {source_code.Path.is_dir.call_args}")
        print(f"source_code.Path.is_dir.method_calls {source_code.Path.is_dir.method_calls}")
        print(f"source_code.Path.is_dir.call_args_list {source_code.Path.is_dir.call_args_list}")
```

After running pytest I get output:

```
test_code.py
<MagicMock name='mock()' id='4278575696'>
#MBB SC: <built-in function dir> -> <MagicMock name='mock().is_dir()' id='4278615568'>
/tmp is a dir
<MagicMock name='mock()' id='4278575696'>
#MBB SC: <built-in function dir> -> <MagicMock name='mock().is_dir()' id='4278615568'>
/tmp/test is a dir

source_code.Path
source_code.Path.call_count 2
source_code.Path.call_args call('/tmp/test')
source_code.Path.method_calls []
source_code.Path.call_args_list [call('/tmp'), call('/tmp/test')]


source_code.Path.is_dir
source_code.Path.is_dir.call_count 0
source_code.Path.is_dir.call_args None
source_code.Path.is_dir.method_calls []
source_code.Path.is_dir.call_args_list []
```

It recognize two mock calls for Path, but don't see mocked is_dir calls. What more it always set result as True. I know that's because result is a mock object. I'm wondering why result is not return value for this mock. What I'm doing wrong in this test?

Answer (score 0):

You call `is_dir` on the object, not on the class, so you need use the return value of the `Path` mock. Also, the call already returns a mock (as each call to a mock does), so there is no need to replace it. Here is a working version (I used a couple of variables to make it more readable):

```py
class TestSourceCode:
    def test(self):
        path_mock = source_code.Path = MagicMock()
        is_dir_mock = path_mock.return_value.is_dir
        is_dir_mock.side_effect = [True, False]

        source_code.simple_method()

        assert path_mock.call_count == 2
        assert path_mock.call_args_list == [call('/tmp'), call('/tmp/test')]
        assert is_dir_mock.call_count == 2
        assert is_dir_mock.call_args_list == [call(), call()]
```

This gives you

```
$ python -m pytest -s
...
<MagicMock name='mock()' id='1399508012056'>
#MBB SC: <built-in function dir> -> True
/tmp is a dir
<MagicMock name='mock()' id='1399508012056'>
#MBB SC: <built-in function dir> -> False
/tmp/test is not a dir
```

As you can see, the side effect is also working now.